# how to retrieve BLOB-23B.bin back as image

Tags: php, blob

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfmO4.png)

I am creating program that stored file uploaded as long blob type. how to retrieve it back as common file?

Data was stored like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO leaves(companyname,responsiblename,description,photos)
        VALUES('$companyname','$responsiblename','$description','$photos')";
```

```
if (isset($_POST['Apply'])){ 
    $companyname = $_POST['companyname']; 
    $responsiblename = $_POST['responsiblename']; 
    $description = $_POST['editor1']; 
    $photos = $_POST['fileToUpload']
```

Comment: That depends upon how and what you stored in in that BLOB, so show us the INSERT process

Comment: @RiggsFolly $sql = "INSERT INTO leaves(companyname,responsiblename,description,photos)VALUES('$companyname','$responsiblename','$description','$photos')";

Comment: Hi John, I asked for the **INSERT Process** not just the insert query, that tells us nothing about what you are storing in the blob, add a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see what you do with the data that came from the user before putting it into the database

Comment: See your other question for notes about [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174)

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's image, mostly like .jpg or .png. I don't  add restrict accept other than image. thx in advance, sorry to blame u

Comment: In future, add extra info to your question, we can read it there

Comment: Ok, now we see the issue. Files are uploaded and the information is placed in the `$_FILES` array so `$photos = $_POST['fileToUpload']` is doing nothing, but should be throwing an error message I would expect. **Are you running with Error Reporting turned OFF?**

Comment: I was adding it but the bot says it mostly code, u can't post it . I tried delete everything so I can post it

Comment: Yes, thats also the reason you are getting DownVotes, the question is lacking any real problem statement, and details are very thin on the ground

Comment: So you get access to the file in the PHP code using the `$_FILES['fileToUpload']` array. Maybe a quick read on the [PHP manual pages for File Uploading](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) would be a good idea right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As "common file" I assume you need to write it to a file.

**Let's start after the point where you retrieve the blob from the db.**

At first, you need to determine the mime type if you didn't save the mime type in the database row.

Then you send the data to the browser

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$result = mysqli_query("select photos from leaves");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$photo=$row['photos'];

$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mimetype = $finfo->buffer($photo);
header("content-type: " . $mimetype);
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($photo));
echo $photo;
```

**VERY VERY IMPORTANT!!!**

**Do not** send output to the browser (ie echo some data) other than **echo $photo**.

If you send output **before** the header() function you get the following error: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at....

If you send output **after** the header() function your image will be corrupted

Comment: sorry I don't understand.var $blob_data_from_db reffer to what? also is it destination path like this -> (img/..) ? thx in advance

Comment: $blob_data_from_db as the variable name says contain the data you stored in the database, as I wrote with the code I start from the point AFTER you retrieved using a query.
As I wrote, I assumed you need to write the data on the disk (you asked "as common file"), $path is the directory where you want to write the file.

I add the query to the database, assuming you use mysql

Comment: ok i getting to likely understand. so $blob_data_from _db is like $photos in my code. there is miss understand here. all I want is when I check the database column photos then click the inside cell, I want the downloaded is back to image file not the blob-23.bin. thx

Comment: ok so you do not want to write to a file but download it via browser. Now the question is you need to download it or to display in a web page? By download, I mean that the browser automatically start a download

Comment: i mean display it in web page

Comment: how to display it in web page?

Comment: The code in the answer already show it in browser, if the browser handle that file type

Comment: but it downloading not showing

Comment: can i email u so i can show what's wrong? maybe u can help

Comment: If we solve it here can be helpful for other people too, you say it download, the downloaded file is correct?

Comment: no it downloaded the page

Comment: I think you have some setting that hide errors, and therefore you do not see the warning try to put:  error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); just before the header("content-type: " . $mimetype); I think you have the "Warning: Cannot modify header information"